# How many nonnegative integer solutions of the inequality $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5<23$ are there with the constraints $x_1 > 2$, $x_2 \geq 3$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5<23$$

$$x_1>2,x_2\ge 3,x_3,x_4,x_5\ge0$$

How can I solve this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I added x7 which is x7>=1 then x7-1

Comment: You probably wanted non-negative integer solutions, not positive integers since you said $_3\ge0$

Comment: Hossein please add your attempts to the question. You may use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math equations.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_i$ are integral, we want to solve for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=22$ with $x_{1,2}\ge3,x_{3,4,5}\ge0$ and $x_6=22-x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4-x_5\ge0$.

Replace $x_1=z_1+3$ and $x_2=z_2+3$ where $z_{1,2}\ge0$. Then you will have$$z_1+z_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6= 22-6=16$$

Using the [stars and bars approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the required answer is$$\binom{21}5=20349.$$